# When using the boxes module, is it possible to export the region and visibility settings?

Tags: 7, blocks

I just installed the Boxes module and I added a box to my feature.  The box description and body were exported successfully, but the region settings (where in the theme(s) the box appears) and the visibility settings (show block on specific pages, etc.) were not.

How can I export the placement information for boxes as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I just realized [there is an issue for this](http://drupal.org/node/1444544) in the boxes queue.  As of May 2012, the issue has been resolved and this is now possible.